# GC is taking mammoth time

Tags: java, garbage-collection

i have faced a situation where GC is taking mamooth time and not sure what can be the reason. Here is the output of `jstat -gc` command

```
S0C     S1C     S0U     S1U EC        EU       OC        OU        PC       PU       YGC  YGCT      FGC FGCT      GCT
77440.0 73088.0 22896.4 0.0 1946624.0 222690.4 4194304.0 3638965.1 262144.0 216641.1 1093 11258.452 3   10031.493 21289.944
```

Full GC ran for 3 times and it took 100031 secs to finish i.e On Avg 55 Min, also YGC is taking 15sec on Avg.

Here is the start up script for the app server:

```
-Xms6144m -Xmx6144m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.security.policy=/bea/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true -da -Dplatform.home=/bea/wlserver_10.3 -Dwls.home=/bea/wlserver_10.3/server -Dweblogic.home=/bea/wlserver_10.3/server -Dweblogic.management.discover=true -Dwlw.iterativeDev=false -Dwlw.testConsole=false -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=false -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=/bea/patch_wls1036/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Duser.timezone=GMT -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Dweblogic.wsee.wstx.wsat.deployed=false -XX:+DisableExplicitGC

Operating system is Sun OS 5.1
Java version 1.6.0_41
```

GC algorithm default, i.e Young Gen is set to PS Scavenge and Old GC is set to PS MarkSweep

What could be the reason for such a high number, please let me know.

Comment: What the hell are you running to get this and where? o.O

Comment: Sun OS 5.1 came out in 1993. Are you sure that's what you are running? If yes, then no wonder about the results. Yes wonder about how you fit 6 gigs of RAM into that machine.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik probably it is using a lot of disk for swapping, which also would explain that huge GC timings.

Comment: The main parameter that causes the GC delays is the used/physical memory ratio. As long as it approaches 1.9, the thrasing become terrible. How can you talk about GC stalls and ignore the memory swapping? Don't you hear it?

Comment: @Val With disks from that era, you can hear them from the hallway :)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, yeah that is some old hardware.  The reason it is that slow is that a 6Gb heap is a huge heap for the default serial collector -- it is designed for heaps not larger than a few hundred megabytes.

I'd try [alternate garbage collectors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#available_collectors.selecting) until you find one that gives you the lowest pauses.  On a multi-gigabyte heap, if such an old machine really does have that much memory, I'd look at -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC and if only one CPU core then additionally -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode.

If you actually have multiple CPUs, I'd look at -XX:+UseParallelGC with -XX:+UseParallelOldGC.   As a last resort you might look at the [G1 collector](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/G1GettingStarted/index.html) which is experimental in Java 6, -XX:+UseG1GC.

UPDATE: Can you rerun your `jstat` with `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` `-XX:+UseParNewGC` `-XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy`?

Comment: `PS MarkSweep` is not a serial collector (PS == Parallel Scavenge).

Comment: Running VMStat for 5 hours has given the following result, i am providing a part of the output:<br/>                                    swap         free re mf pi po
40336468 4025208 383 5473 465 59
40336132 4025732 383 5477 465 59
40336020 4025732 383 5478 465 59
40335940 4025752 383 5479 465 59
40335860 4025776 383 5479 465 59
40335776 4025796 383 5480 465 59
40335696 4025816 383 5481 465 59
40335584 4025816 383 5482 464 59
40335504 4025836 383 5483 464 59
40335420 4025856 383 5484 464 59

Comment: Could you please add VMState output to your original post. This way it would have reasonable formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Running VMStat for 5 hours has given the following result, i am providing a part of the output:
 swap           free     re mf  pi  po

40336468    4025208 383 5473    465 59 
40336132    4025732 383 5477    465 59 
40336020    4025732 383     5478    465 59 
40335940    4025752 383 5479    465 59 
40335860    4025776 383 5479    465 59 
40335776    4025796 383 5480    465 59 
40335696    4025816 383 5481    465 59 
40335584    4025816 383 5482    464 59 
40335504        4025836 383 5483    464 59 
40335420    4025856 383 5484    464 59

Comment: For the casual reader, this show basically no swapping activity.

Comment: This is from Solaris machine, pi and po represents swapping activity.

Comment: Yes, I know.  And it's indicating that 465Kb have been paged in, and 59Kb have been paged out.  That's nothing.  Certainly nothing approaching what one would call "swapping".

Answer (score 0):

Look at your original jstat these are the things I notice...

You are getting full GC in the old generation because it is being highly utilized (3.5G used of 4G available).

By default, the VM splits the heap roughly 45/55 between Young (Eden+Survivor) and Old generation, but also applies some heuristics.

Eden capacity is 1.9G, but utilization is only 217M (~12%).  Survival spaces are about 75M each, with utilization of about 22M.  Old generation is 4G and utilization is high at 3.5G.

What this looks like to me is a bit of over-aggressive promotion from Young to Old, mixed with poorly sized Young and Old for your needs.  Young seems to be somewhat oversized for your needs.  However, fixing the over-aggressive promotion does require space in Young.

First, to adjust Young:

```
-XX:NewRatio=5
```

This will set Young (Eden+Survivor) to 1/6 of the total heap (*yes, 1/6 not 1/5*).  In your case, ~980M rather than 1.9G.  This will push another 1G over to the Old generation heap.

Second, let's try to keep medium-lived objects from being promoted too quickly.  Try:

```
-XX:InitialTenuringThreshold=16 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=32
```

But to keep survivors around longer before promoting, we need to increase the Survivor spaces (carving a bit out of Eden):

```
-XX:SurvivorRatio=6
```

Combine this with the options from my first answer, and your options, in total you get:

```
-Xms6144m -Xmx6144m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:NewRatio=5
-XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -XX:InitialTenuringThreshold=16 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=32
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
```

You might want to add:

```
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
```

While investigating these options.

Comment: If this works, as I am confident that it will, please mark this as the correct answer.